# Find a record in existing resultset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

Let's say I did a find all on a model

```
@projects = Project.all
```

Now I would like find an individual record within the resultset just returned without having to make it another SQL call. This line of code triggers a new SQL call, I'll like to avoid it if possible, figures there should be a way to grab the record from the resultset

```
@projects.find(1)
```

Comment: it might be a good thing to add a scope/finder to your Projects model, even though that might trigger another query, but it would improve readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@projects` is just an array of Project objects now you can simply use any ruby operator that operates on arrays to find the object you want.

For example:

```
@projects.first {|item| item.id == 1}
```

is the same as your example.

You could also use something like:

```
 @projects.select {|item| item.foo == 3}
```

if you knew you could match multiple items.

Comment: Yep, I came to the same conclusion independently and used `select` method. Couple of minor notes about your example, it should be `item.foo == 3` and `first` should be added at the end like `project = @projects.select {|item| item.foo == 3}.first`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer `@projects.detect { |item| item.foo == 3 }` over `@projects.select { |item| item.foo == 3 }.first`, because it stops the iteration upon finding the first match.

Comment: Sweet, even better, there is only ever 1 match anyway in my scenario. `detect` is an enumerable method though in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: I'm coding Ruby for almost 4 years, but I discovered `detect` only earlier this year. This is the reason, why I love Ruby. There are lots of good surprises to discover! :)